# Post request in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I have android application which will send me some data in POST request to my rails app. How to handle that Post request in rails i.e How do I write POST api for android app. I have some knowledge about scaffolding in rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See "[Rails' guide to routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)."

The routing process is used to map a HTTP verb, like "POST", to a particular controller's action. Typically, for Rails apps, the conventional method is `MyController#create`. In that controller, you will respond to the action with respond_to and a format for the response as mentioned in [the Rails controller tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data).

Your response will be based on the model implementing a serializer, or even better, delegating to a serializer for it, in order to create the API response for your Android app.